# Where can I find an efficient R-Tree implementation?

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, c, tree

I'm looking for an R-Tree implementation, in C, Objective-c and even C++, which shall be efficient for searching the 2d rectangle in which a point falls ( memory efficiency would also be great, but I can sacrifice a bit more memory for time even while I am on an iPhone ). A good documentation will be appreciated too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20130102141049/http://www.chorochronos.org/?q=algorithms), it provides implementations (in C, C++, Java, etc.) for several variants (R*, R+, etc.).

Comment: I found it too on the web, it appears that the same code has been ported through different languages. I will test it and let you know ^^